# Why doesn't imfindcircles work when trying to find circles in an image with dense packing of circles?

Tags: image, matlab, computer-vision

[image: The picture I am using to identify each sphere in the image]

The code:

```
A = rgb2gray(imread('Capture.PNG'));
imshow(A)
[centers, radii, metric] = imfindcircles(A,[12 17]);
```

I don't understand as to why this won't work because the picture size dimensions are 155x185 and I used ImageJ to find the diameter of one sphere (approx 30 pixels).

My goal is to identify the individual spheres. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't have the Image Processing Toolbox right now but I've done things like this before.

My guess is that you'll have to do edge detection first (https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/edge-detection.html#responsive_offcanvas).  You should probably set the threshold low to get lots of edges and then refine them with morphological operators.  You might be able to get away w/o refining the initial set of edges if you play w/ the Sensitivity and EdgeThreshold parameters of imfindcircles.  Looks fun!

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. I tried playing with the edge threshold and sensitivity parameters however they yielded a lot of false positives. How do I change the threshold and refine with morphological operators? I applied the Edge detection filters however the image is very fuzzy.  https://imgur.com/a/Habt3Ig     This picture has the image after filtering

Comment: Wow, those edges are bad!  I think you'll have to get the brightness and color about equal across the image (try histeq) and then maybe a template matching approach would be better (the template you would be trying to match would be one ball).